How do I set the max age for a cache entry when calling fetch?
I may be fundamentally misunderstanding something here but it seems to me that if I want to fetch something I can call
let r = await fetch("someurl");

and the browser will use a cached version if it has one. Or I could call
let r = await fetch("someurl", {
  cache: "reload"
});

and I would always get a new version.
What I cannot find is how to tell it that I only want the cached version if it is younger than X minutes.
I could do
let r = await fetch("someurl", {
  headers: {
    "Cache-control": "max-age=180"
  }
});

but afaiu that would just get sent to the server and not actually impact what the browser is doing about values in its own cache.

The cache control of the response is set by the server. You can either accept the expiration the server sets, or turn caching off. There's no way to change the cache expiration of existing content on the client side.

When you couple this with the possibility that there are possibly going to be several "clients" between the browser and the origin server (think CDNs, proxies and gateways) in the real world, the only realistic way of correctly controlling caching policy throughout that chain is by setting the correct response headers at the origin server.

@spender I am dealing with the case where I want to download a file hosted by somebody else and I want to control how often it gets re-downloaded.

Parametrize cache value so, that it changes from default to reload in 180 secs interval.

Oh, I think those would totally be viable options. I would effectively implement my own cache or at least the expiration tracking. I just expected this to exist.

Actually, what's the magic in 180 secs? Wouldn't cache: 'default' do the trick, the request will load only fresh data ..?

I think the issue here is who decides what they think is "fresh enough" the client or the server.

In theory you can actually do exactly what you said:
let r = await fetch("someurl", {
  headers: {
    "Cache-Control": "max-age=180"
  }
});

That's because Cache-Control is a request header as well as a response header:

The max-age request directive indicates that the client prefers a response whose age is less than or equal to the specified number of seconds.

My impression in the past was that browser caches don't respect this request header, though, so I'm not sure offhand how well this will work in practice.
